# HTML loads default language before loading right language

Tags: javascript, html, localization

I have an HTML file with `<html lang="en">`.

Then in the JavaScript code I set the language according to the browser's language. The HTML file is being used offline. If the payload of it is really big, e.g. 128MB you can see the site first showing in English and after a few milliseconds changing to the browser's language. Is it possible to define the language before the UI is shown? If yes, how?

Comment: Sort of. Only if you don't display *any* text until it's loaded then add in the text for the correct language.

Comment: Show us the file and anything else that may matter.

Comment: I have the feeling that all questions without code are being downvoted, I don't understand, my question is legitim, without code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to define the language in a separate script tag that is positioned before the other UI elements because the HTML file is rendered from top to bottom.